# How to index paths/tree in Elastic Search using python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, path, tree

I need to index documents against a set of tags and one or more tree paths.

How can I use `path_hierarchy` with the Python ES API to be able to get results with filtering on the Path hierarchy ?

[this is a NEST partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135916/mapping-and-indexing-path-hierarchy-in-elastic-nest-to-search-with-in-directory)

[allusion made to parent-child here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38402027/how-do-i-index-hierarchical-data-in-elastic-search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use [Path Hierarchy Tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html)?

Seems like your solution to describe a hierarchy.